# Why map and reduce run at the same time?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am newbie on Hadoop. I remember I learned from somewhere that in Hadoop, all map functions have to be completed before reduce functions can start off.

But I just got the printout when I run a map reduce program like this:

```
map(15%), reduce(5%)
map(20%), reduce(7%)
map(30%), reduce(10%)
map(38%), reduce(17%)
map(40%), reduce(25%)
```

why they run in parallel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before actual Reduce phase starts, **Shuffle**, **Sort** and **Merge** take place as Mappers keep on completing. This percentage signifies that. It is not the actual Reduce phase. This happens in parallel to reduce the overhead which would otherwise be incurred if framework keeps on waiting for completion of all the Mappers first and then do the Shuffling, Sorting and Merging.

Comment: Yes, and goes without saying that the reducers also have to copy mapper output data before having anything to shuffle. That's also a lot of this progress.

Comment: @SeanOwen : Correctly said sir.

Comment: thanks guys, that said, Hadoop puts things like Shuffle, Sort .... into percentage of reducing process? why not in map process?

Comment: Because there is nothing to Shuffle, Sort or Merge before Map phase. It happens on the key-value pairs emitted by the mappers which is not possible before the Map phase.

Comment: The mapper will also sort its own subset of output on the map side -- this is also how it is able to run a combiner. But it has to be sorted/merged with other mappers' output on the reduce side too.